# Render different categories in tabs with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm having trouble to make this work. I have my model "Food", which belongs_to category, and I have my model "Category" which has many foods.

Food has a category_id column to reference it's category. Simple.

I want to render a different category of food in each tab with AJAX, but I'm desperate with it.

I'm using Refills for my tabs, and they are working perfectly with static html content.

**The problem comes when I want to populate each tab with the foods in each category.**

**My View**

```
<section class="col-8">
<ul class="categories accordion-tabs">
  <li class="tab-header-and-content">
   <% @categories.each do |tab| %>
      <%= link_to tab.name, category_path(tab), class: "tab-link" %>
      <div class="category tab-content">
      </div>
   <% end %>
   </li>
  </ul>
</section>

<script>
$(".categories").on("click", "a", function() {
   $.ajax({
       url: $(this).attr("href"),
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(data) {
           $(".tab-content").html(data)
       }
   });
});
</script>
```

**My routes**

```
  resources :categories, only: [:show]

My Categories Controller

class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @category = Category.find params[:id]
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.json { render json: @category.foods.to_json }
        end
    end 
end
```

**My Category show view**

```
<% @category.foods.each do |food| %>
    <%= image_tag food.food_image_url(:food_small), class: "radius" %>
    <h5> <%= food.name %> </h5>
    <span class="small"><i class="icon-list"></i> <%= food.ingredients %></span>
    <span class="medium block textright">
    <% if food.price === "Verde" %>
    <%= image_tag "verde.png" %>
    <% elsif food.price === "Azul" %>
    <%= image_tag "azul.png" %>
    <% elsif food.price === "Amarillo" %>
    <%= image_tag "amarillo.png" %>
    <% elsif food.price === "Rojo" %>
    <%= image_tag "rojo.png" %>
    <% elsif food.price === "Morado" %>
    <%= image_tag "morado.png" %>
    <% end %>
    </span>
<% end %>
```

My foods #index Controller

```
    def index
      @addictfood = Addictfood.last
      @categories = Category.all.limit(7)
      @food = Food.last
      @foods = Food.all
  end
```

I don't really now how to make this work. Please help! Thanks a lot

Comment: make what work? Need to be a little more specific about what your problems are

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry about that.

Comment: @charlietfl I want to render the foods in each category in each tab. I  have an each that prints the names of the categories in the tabs, but I want to populate each tab with the foods in its category. If I put /categories/1.json, I'm getting correctly all of the foods in that category, but I don't know why that JSON is not being printed in each tab in my view.

Comment: will need to target different `<div>` for each in your success. Can use indexing or incremental ID instead of `$(".tab-content")` which will target all with same class in page